# How to filter the correct line in sheet instead of IF-statement (Excel)

Tags: excel

In my excel sheet i have the following function:

```
=IF(AD51="European"; 
    IF(P51<50.000.000; 0,05%; 
        IF(P51<75.000.000; 0,045%;
            IF(P51<100.000.000; 0,04%;
                IF(P51<125.000.000; 0,037%;
                    IF(P51<150.000.000; 0,035%;
                        IF(P51<200.000.000; 0,034%;
                            IF(P51<250.000.000; 0,033%;
                                IF(P51<300.000.000; 0,032%;
                                    IF(P51<400.000.000; 0,031%;
                                        IF(P51<500.000.000; 0,03%;0,025)
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );"American")
```

Well, I need to replace this in an extra sheet in order to avoid this kind of IF function in a cell.

Here the table:

[image]

My question is, how to get the result in the marked cells below:
[image]

I need to check if the `ID` is existing in CalcSheet (Screenshot1) and then to check in which rank the `Volume` value is categorized in MasterSheet (Screenshot2).  Finished the table have to return the %-value of the CalcSheet.

> EDIT: I tried it with `VLOOKUP(A2;Ranking;3)` but I get always the
>   same procent => 0,03. For your information, `Ranking` is the range of
>   the Screenshot1 that I named it.

Comment: put your values in another sheet and use a vlookup?

Comment: @MatBailie Could you help me please? I'm not a pro in excel.

Comment: @pnuts but i need to compare the id, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Complex Lookups in Excel

Solution to your problem using SUMIFS

**Updated MasterSheet**

[image: MasterSheet]

**CalcSheet with Formula**
[image]

Formula in CalcSheet!C2:

=SUMIFS(MasterSheet!$D$2:$D$11,MasterSheet!$A$2:$A$11,A2,MasterSheet!$E$2:$E$11,E2,MasterSheet!$C$2:$C$11,">"&B2,MasterSheet!$B$2:$B$11,"<="&B2)

**Explanation**

VLOOKUP is quite limited in its ability to pick up values. This neat trick with SUMIFS allows fairly complex lookup based on multiple conditions. The trick here is to first ensure that you select one and only cell using conditions and then sum over that one cell.

In this case, we sum over column D in MasterSheet. The conditions are:

1. MasterSheet Column A matches CalcSheet Column A
2. MasterSheet Column E matches CalcSheet Column E
3. MasterSheet Column C is greater than CalcSheet Column B
4. MasterSheet Column B is less or equal to CalcSheet Column B

Please mark this as answer if this solves your problem.

> **Update in response to OP's comment**
>
> Like the above 4 conditions. You can choose up-to 127 ranges and corresponding conditions in Sumifs in Excel 2016. Check [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60530&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) in Office Documentation.

Comment: I had a error in my sheet... Thank you very much for your help. Do you know how to dynamically select in MasterSheet all columns? Because I have an any number of data.

Comment: Please could you define an example just with MAX without MIN?

Comment: Min is required, otherwise multiple rows would match the condition. You can put the min column after all the other columns (in Column F) if you don't want to change the position of other columns. The revised formula will be: =SUMIFS(MasterSheet!$D$2:$D$11,MasterSheet!$A$2:$A$11,A2,MasterSheet!$E$2:$E$11,E2,MasterSheet!$C$2:$C$11,">"&B2,MasterSheet!$F$2:$F$11,"<="&B2)